# When matter and antimatter meet and annihilate, is that considered 'decay'? By the EM, weak and strong forces simultaneously?

Tags: forces, particle-physics, antimatter

Matter-antimatter destruction is 'decay', correct?  And since antimatter particles are considered the opposite of matter ones in every way, not just in terms of EM charge, does that mean they are decaying via all three quantum forces simultaneously?

Comment: Decay normally means the decay of a single isolated particle. A particle and antiparticle colliding and annihilating would be scattering rather than a decay.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, "decay" refers to reactions where the initial state consists of only one object, so matter-antimatter annihilation is not decay.

As an aside, whether or not a reaction "involves" all three types of "forces" (strong, weak, EM) depends on how small of a correction you're willing to look at. Generally, *every* interaction technically involves all three "forces" if you consider arbitrarily small corrections. For example, if you carry out the calculation of an electromagnetic interaction to arbitrarily high orders, you're going to see some contributions from Z bosons replacing photons, and from photons splitting into quark-antiquark pairs and then those quarks radiating gluons. Generally these contributions are pretty tiny compared to the tree-level, photon-only interaction.